# LibreOffice crashes too often?

Tags: software-recommendation

LibreOffice Crashes too often,

Here is the version that I'm using:

> LibreOffice 3.3.3 
>   OOO330m19 (Build:301)
>   tag libreoffice-3.3.3.1, Ubuntu package 1:3.3.3-1ubuntu2

### Edit:

How it got crashed.
I"m currently running Chrome Browser with minimum 7+ tabs and a terminal plus a VLC Video streaming and also a update manager was running in the background. Whenever I edit something in LibreOffice, it crashes up randomly. Now I'm not able to reproduce it. But it happens randomly. Is it because I sometimes close the laptop lid.

### edit version 2:

Here are few related queries posted in LibreOffice:

1. http://listarchives.libreoffice.org/global/users/msg02500.html
2. http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=621501

I normally use touchpad for cursor movement and also use right-clicks more often while doing spell-check.

Comment: Can you add some detail... like what version of Ubuntu, what triggers the crash...

Comment: This should be filed as a bug.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I stop LibreOffice from randomly crashing?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41329/how-can-i-stop-libreoffice-from-randomly-crashing)

Comment: could you please check out this possible duplicate ( http://askubuntu.com/questions/41329/how-can-i-stop-libreoffice-from-randomly-crashing) and try to determine if it is the same bug? (Note that I don't think this other question has actually been solved) For instance, does the crash happen more often just after resume from suspend or resume from screensaver? Do you have java enabled in LO? And are you using LO-menubar?

Answer (score 3):

What version of Ubuntu are you using ? I don't think LibreOffice crashes too often, but if you are using some pre-release version well that may be the problem. An alternative would be OpenOffice

Comment: You should split any questions into comments, and leave the suggestion in your answer.

Comment: You're right, but I can't actually comment, yet. (I think[?])

Comment: I believe you should be able to now.