# Ubuntu sometimes freezes when switching instances via Unity’s Launcher

Tags: 12.04, launcher, freeze

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 for a friend of mine and she often complains about freezes. I never saw these freezes myself, so I can only give the description she gave me:

- it happens when switching between multiple instances of an application via Unity’s *Launcher*

  - after the click at the Launcher, she sees a preview of all running instances; when selecting one, it zooms in, and then Ubuntu freezes
- it happens for Evince and LibreOffice (but it’s rare that she opens several instances of any other programs)
- if it freezes, she is still able to switch to the virtual terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)
- but: it can’t be reproduced; some days it doesn’t happen, some days it happens 3 times per hour

For a long time it happened with LibreOffice only, so I searched for possible solutions and [disabled anti-aliasing](https://askubuntu.com/a/121444/82665); after this it never crashed again when switching LibreOffice instances, but it’s not a long time ago and so it might just be luck.

Any idea what could cause this resp. how to fix it?

Anything I could do to investigate it? The problem, as I said, is that it never happened when I was around; and we never managed to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than two years ago, I switched to **Unity 2D**, after which the problem never occurred again.

I don’t know what the problem with Unity (3D) is.

Answer (score 0):

My desktop was freezing up and when it would wake up it would be in another place.  I think your girl friend is having the same problem.The fix for me since never wanting my machine to go to sleep was to edit `/etc/defaults/acpi-support` and change the line to `SUSPEND_METHODS="none"`. Good Luck, hope this helps....